# Select_and_Order Field not saving empty value

Tags: laravel, laravel-backpack

I have a field in my CRUD create/update view that is a select_and_order field:

```
CRUD::addField([
            'name'  => 'menu_items',
            'label' => "Your Custom Navigation Menu",
            'type'  => 'select_and_order',
            'options' => [
                1 => "Option 1",
                2 => "Option 2"
            ]
],);
```

It allows me to save it blank and it stays blank, it allows me to save any option, in any order. However, once I have saved an option, it then will not allow me to save it when all options are removed. It simply reverts to the last value that was saved.

I have the field in the DB as a JSON field that is nullable.

I have checked that the field is fillable and I have also cast the field as an array in the model.

```
protected $fillable = [
        ...
        'menu_items',
        ...
];

protected $casts = [
        'id' => 'integer',
        'menu_items' => 'array',
];
```

I also tried with and without a rule in the request.

I can see from the backpack demo site, that this is working correctly. What am I doing wrong?

TIA

Comment: Ouch! This is gonna be a tricky one  I've just tried it in our demo, can confirm it's working fine _usually_. And you seem to have already checked "_the usual suspects_". But still... something somewhere in your code _must be_ interfering with the saving process. I recommend you start using `dd()` in different places to figure out WHERE exactly the information gets lost. I'd start with the Request, then the Model, as a mutator... Sorry I can't be of more help, no bright ideas ‍♂️

Comment: Shot in the dark - maybe you have a `setMenuItemsAttribute()` mutator in your Model and don't know about it? Or a relationship with a name that conflicts with this attribute in the Model?

Comment: Thanks so much for your help with this @tabacitu . I really appreciate it! I tried removing validation altogether. I also tried to use the same field in a different model and got the same issue. I renamed the field, created a new database field and still it operates in the same way. It saves correctly when there are values, but reverts if I remove them all. It's super strange.

Comment: Could it be an add-on I installed? I have DevTools, Permissions Manager and a few other small ones. I'm new to backpack and am not sure where else to look.

Comment: No, I don't see a way for add-ons to interfere with this... only custom code...

Comment: Maybe you're using Model Events somewhere... or Model Observers?

Comment: @tabacitu I've even tried using the same field on a different model with the same results. Where else could this be happening? In one of the middlewares maybe?

Comment: @tabacitu some more info that may help... I created a mutator so I can debug with dd(). It gets triggered correctly when there is a value to save, but is not even triggered when I move all the options out the save_and_order field. Hopefully that narrows down where this could be happening.

Comment: That's exactly what made me think it's a mutator causing it. Because it sounds like a mutator behaviour - if NULL then do not call.

Comment: What if you save the same information... from a `php artisan tinker` session? What is the value when you move all the options out the save_and_order field? Try to manually set that value in a tinker session... what happens, does it get saved? If not, then the problem is in the model. If it does, then the problem is something that's happening in the admin panel (EntityCrudController or EntityRequest).

Comment: @tabacitu I'm still getting nowhere on this. Could really use any help you can think of. Some addl info on my end. 1. I tried using a mutator on the model and it only fires if the field has a value. 2. I tried using a 'saved' event to the field while adding it and if I remove the options from the select field it shows the original value. 3. If I write the value to the console window using JS and the onChange event I see the value zeroing out. This makes me think it is happening in the Controller.

Comment: If I use the update() function and dd() the updateTrait, I also see the unchanged values. Somewhere it's definitely saying 'if null, skip' or something along those lines.